# Grid Telerik Kendo UI - Deletar row JS e chamar função

Tags: javascript, html5, template, kendo-ui, telerik

Estou adicionando linhas normalmente e adicionando em um array JavaScript, preciso remover uma linha selecionada e remover do array e por ultimo salvar no banco.
O trecho abaixo não esta funcionando corretamente, apenas chama uma função mas não ativa o comando "destroy" do telerik:

```
template: "<a href='javascript:DeleteRow(this);' data-command='destroy'>Remover</a>"
```

Se for possível remover pela função a linha seria ótimo, mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: template: "<a href='javascript:DeleteRow(this);' data-command='destroy'>Remover</a>"

Comment: Onde está o conteúdo da sua função `DeleteRow()` ?